# Can you prevent a div from being dynamically created?

Tags: jquery, google-chrome-extension

I have a chrome extension which triggers an event when one hovers over a div element.

Now, there is a collision problem since the same div element is being used to trigger the creation and display of a div which interferes with my event that creates and displays a div too.

The new event appears to be triggered by a hover (I do not have access to the code) to display the div. That div closes when the mouse leaves.

This code closes/hides the div but does not hide the div fast enough so it is clunky to say the least:

```
$(this).mousemove(function(e) {
$(".badpopup").hide();
});
```

I only have the class available to work with.

So, is there any way to prevent any divs with the class `.badpopup` being created or hidden in a more efficient and less clunky way?

Comment: Maybe [preventDefualt](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just set the class to hidden.

.badpopup {
  display: none !important;
}

There's a plugin called livequery that will detect if a new popup with classname of .badpopup is created and you can remove it that way. But that might be overkill. You could just use the CSS above with something like a 30-second setInterval().

Comment: Yikes! The first thing I tried was `$('.badpopup').css("display","none")` without success in the script.  Just put your solution in the .css and voilà. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could try to detect if it exists in your page load function, and hide it then. I'm not sure if it's the most efficient way, but it will solve your lag problem that comes from `mousemove()`

```
if($('.badpopup').length) { //checks for existence
$('.badpopup').hide();
}
```

Comment: Thanks but that didn't work for some reason. The .css approach did.